# ASP.Net SSRS Report Viewer 9.0 and Report Viewer 10.0 Side-By-Side

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer

We are rolling out a large deployment of SQL Server Reporting Services Reports and our platform is SQL Server 2005 so our Report Server is version 2005 running in Native mode. Our web application uses server reports rendered in the Report Viewer 9.0 control. We want to be able to use local reports based on the 2008 RDL spec to create some dashboard applications. We also would like to use the new report viewer 10.0 to viewer these reports.

Is there a way to run these both Side-By-Side in the same project? If so how would we go about that? Create a custom server control?

Comment: One Idea we are tossing around is having all of the report viewer 10 reports as a separate application and display them in an IFrame in the main application. Not sure if there are any quirks with the report viewer 10.0 in an IFrame but I will report back.

Comment: Have you considered not using the viewer to render the server reports and just redirecting to the URL on the server? This way version of the SSRS server can be supported along side your local mode reports.

Answer (score 0):

Install both versions in the GAC.

Register both versions on the page using:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb10" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb9" %>
```

and finally use the controls like this `<rsweb10:ReportViewer />` and `<rsweb9:ReportViewer />`